# Folder structure to handle projects shared libs in Delphi/Lazarus

Tags: delphi, environment-variables, lazarus, freepascal

My projects share many common libraries and sometimes one project should use different version of the code library. And some of the libraries was patched by me to correct the bugs.

How to organize folders structure to make initial project setup easier?

Comment: Is this a question about Delphi or about FreePascal? The tags say Lazarus and FreePascal, but you mention Delphi. Which is it?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I've updated the title and the answer. Now it describes both.

Answer (score 0):

**Keeping the code libs**

To share code libraries we should use a shared code repository, e.g. VCS repository or just a shared folder.
For better navigation create a tree structure, use paths like this one `lib-name\lib-name-version`. Version can be a version number, version name, VCS changeset id, or any other string to indicate the lib version. If you want to add a patched or adopted by you version of the library name it like `lib-name-version-private` and add PatchInfo.txt describing your changes for other developers. You can also keep a compiled lib DCU-files for libs without a source code.

Example libs repository structure:

```
+ superobject
|  |- superobject-1.1
|  +- superobject-1.2
+ synapse
|  |- synapse-1.0
|  |- synapse-r209
|  +- synapse-r209-private
+indy
   |- indy-9.0
   +- indy-10.0.0.52
```

**Accessing libs / Library Path**

To allow any developer keep the libraries anywhere he wants use OS Environment Vars. Delphi IDE/Lazarus IDE in project options or IDE Library Path can replace $(env-var-name) macros with env var value during build. 
Create an env var `PascalCommonLibs=D:\PascalCommonLibs`, specify a path to your libs repository root, then add libs you want to Library Path.

Library Path Example for Delphi:

```
$(PascalCommonLibs)\superobject\superobject-1.2
$(PascalCommonLibs)\synapse\synapse-r209-private
```

Library Path Example for Lazarus:

```
$Env(PascalCommonLibs)\superobject\superobject-1.2
$Env(PascalCommonLibs)\synapse\synapse-r209-private
```

Now you even can create a default Library Path list which every developer can just paste into the IDE Library Path.

This method also simplifies automated build configuration, just use `PascalCommonLibs` env var in scripts to specify library or source search path.

Comment: Unfortunately Delphi doesn't work very well with relative paths. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326041/relative-paths-in-delphi-projects-and-ite-in-particular) That way there are still hardcoded paths in your projects that must change if you e.g. want to build an old version with old component. Otherwise you could simply check the components/ and apps/ on the same level, and have all your apps refer to ../../components/x

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort But it's not relative $(DelphiCommonLibs)\superobject\superobject-1.2 would be evaluated to absolute path D:\DelphiCommonLibs\superobject\superobject-1.2.

Comment: Yeah, that is the limitation I want to avoid :-)

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort Actually, as I see It's the only way to  set path quite cheap avoiding the problem with relative paths. What do you use hardcoded paths?

Comment: Hardcodes paths is that I have to change configuration for two different checkouts. Which includes subst tricks or environment changes.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but afaik in Lazarus relative paths are relative to the location of the .lpr, not the (random) working dir.